# Translating unknown language with AI

Tags: machine-translation

I've read around the web there are AI's they used to translate ancient languages, even without any comparation with known texts.

What I wasn't unable to find, is the specifications of those AIs, and the procedure they used to obtain a working software.

That is, what kind of operating system do they run on? What kind of personalization do they require? (I mean, beyond giving the images of the symbols of the language to translate).

Also, what's the size of the software and the related data? Is it open source? Is it downloadable so it can be used by anyone?

As a thought experiment, let's guess you are an explorer and find some book or other stuff with an unknown language - no context and no relationship with anything else. You want keep it secret and translate it by yourself, and you want use those AIs. Can you download from some university or whatever and run it?

(I'm aware it's a long shot, but one never knows)

EDIT following Draconis' comment, I'd like to know if the original problem could be solved, adding a small Rosetta stone-like table of translated words. I've no idea how big such a table should be, so let's guess it's very small. In this case, do downloadable AI exist that can be fed with the original text and that table and do some translation?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such systems. Certainly nobody's been able to produce a convincing decipherment of Linear A, or the Voynich Manuscript, or the Rongorongo tablets, with AI or without. (Plenty of people _claim_ they have but their decipherments never agree and seldom have any way to verify them.)

Comment: @Draconis would the situation change if we factor in the problem a small Rosetta stone with some translated words? I'm adding an edit in the post about this.

Comment: This cannot be answered in the abstract. One would have to find or invent one and apply it to some obcure language.